# How can I append date and time to node titles?

Tags: nodes

I want to append the date and time to node titles. For example, If the title is *Test*, I want to change it to *Test_DDMMYY_hhmmss*.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This will do for you

```
function modulename_node_presave($node) {
      if($node->type == 'node_type_machine_name') {
        $new_date = date("DMY_hms", time());
        $node->title = $node->title."_".$new_date;
      }
}
```

Comment: Where am i need to add this?

Comment: if you had custom module you can add it there

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Automatic Nodetitles](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module to do it without code. In combination with the [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module you can build complex patterns.

Comment: Is there is any option to append the entered title with date?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `hook_node_presave()`. This should get you started.

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node){
  if ($node->type == "my_content_type") {
    $node->title = $node->title . "_" . date('dmy_his');
  }
}
```

Though I am only inferring that you want date and time of when the node was saved.

Comment: I am new for Drupal. May i know where am i need to add this Function?

Comment: You probably want to put it in a module. In the `modules` directory, you must create a folder for your module. In this example I would have a `my_test` folder, with files named `my_test.module` and `my_test.info`.

This function would go in the `my_test.module` file.

Comment: i just copied the function in my_test.module file but its not working

Comment: in your info declare these name = Test module
package = Custom Modules
description = Module for LO Admin related code
core = 7.x

files[] = my_test.module

Comment: @Sam1604, I believe there's a bare minimum you need in the .info file:  

    name = My Test Module
    description = Test module
    core = 7.x

Then of course you must enable the module.

Comment: Enabled Test Module in my project, while saving the data it shows "function my_test_node....." in the top. The title is saved as usual (Test) not like (Test_ddmmyy_hhss). Am i need to edit something in Function?

Comment: What is the machine name of the content type of the node you are saving?

Comment: That's your local server. The node you're saving is of a particular content type, like page or article. If you copied that function, you'll have to change `my_content_type`.